# InvalidCastException on ListItem Click (Mono for Android)

Tags: c#, android, android-listview, xamarin.android, .net

**1.)** My `main.xml` contains :

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/lsym"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**2.)** After populating the list, I'm assigning an `adapter` to it as follows :

```
lsym.Adapter=new SymbolAdapter(this,result);
```

where `result` is a `DataTable`.

**3.)** Within `SymbolAdapter`, I have used :

```
convertView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.list_symbol, null);
```

**4.)** `list_symbol.xml` contains :

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/symbolLayout" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tvsym" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**5.)** And finally, for list item click, I'm using following code snippet:

```
   lsym.ItemClick+= SearchItem_Click;
```

&

```
   private void SearchItem_Click(object sender, ItemEventArgs e)
        {
            string  company=((TextView)e.View).Text;
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Selected="+company,ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
```

as specified [here](http://docs.monodroid.net/index.aspx?link=T:Android.Widget.ListView).

But when *I click a list item, it is giving me following error :*

```
System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
SearchItem_Click (object,Android.Widget.ItemEventArgs)
```

at `((TextView)e.View).Text`.

ANY IDEA WHY THIS IS HAPPENING?
I know I have put up lot of code but as I'm absolute beginner to mono for android, so any help appreciated.

Comment: final TextView company = (TextView) findViewById(R.id."the_id_of_your_textview");

Comment: debug code and check what exactly is e.View ... surely not TextView

Comment: @litemode i just have to say that ... lol ... calling findViewById will not work here since you will call it from Activity ... but it may help if he use e.View.findViewById ...

Comment: @Selvin - `company=((TextView)e.View.FindViewById(Resource.Id.tvsym)).Text.Trim();` WORKED !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e.View` is `RelativeLayout` so casting it to TextView will not work ...
instead of this you should call  `FindViewById(Resource.Id.tvsym)` on that view ( not just plain since it will be called on Activity)

code should looks like:

`TextView rowText = (TextView)e.View.FindViewById(Resource.Id.tvsym);`

EDIT: or in Mono you can use:

`TextView rowText = e.View.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvsym);`